# Error:Exception: You do not have permission to call Session.getActiveUser. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

Tags: google-apps-script, v8, google-apps-script-runtime

I recently migrated one of my projects to the new V8 engine of appscript.I am getting this exception

> Exception: You do not have permission to call Session.getActiveUser.
>   Required permissions:
>   https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email..Session.getActiveUser
>   is not accessible without permission

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: I ran into a several similar situations recently and in each case I tried adding the scope to my manifest folder even though it was already in Project Properties/ Info and I was able to continue.  I don't have any explanation beyond that.  Perhaps it will work for you.

Comment: Even I added the scope to my manifest folder..still no luck

Comment: I suppose it's time to submit it as an issue.

Comment: Try using Session.getEffectiveUser()

Comment: Please share the function that is throwing this error in your question.

Comment: I experienced this precise issue with 2 scripts that were automatically migrated to V8. Reverting them to Rhino resolved the issue. I have reviewed the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime) and can find no explicit reason why this should fail. I am about to file an issue. Please advise if you have done so already so I can upvote instead of duplicating.

Comment: There is an [issue filed for this already](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149413836). Please star if you're experiencing this issue.

Comment: Apparently, the error disappeared..not sure how

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @zimday this isssue has been already reported in [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker).

You can follow the issue in [**this link**](https://issuetracker.google.com/149413836). Give it a `+1` to make Google aware of the people affected by it.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @Raserhin, there's an open issue with google and the problem seems to be with the new App Script runtime powered by Chrome v8.

A small workaround (until the issue is resolved) will be to disable the App Script runtime as follows: (Run -> Disable App Script runtime powered by Chrome V8). The project will now run with Apps Script Legacy which does not have this issue.